# Erlang regular expression must match entire string

Tags: regex, erlang

I am trying to write some code to validate a list of colon separated k/v pairs in erlang. I can get the following expression to match a single pair.

```
re:run(Tag, "^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,50}:[^:][ ]?[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-\\_\\+]{1,50})")
```

So, if I pass a tag of key:value it matches as expected. But, I need it to NOT match if I pass something like key:value:123. It appears that what is happening is that re returns {match, Match} if any part of the string matches. However, I need it to only return match if the ENTIRE string matches. Is there a way to do this in erlang? I read-over the docs at http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html and tried a few things with options but have yet to figure it out.

Comment: Did you try adding a `$` at the end of your regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `$` on the end to match the full line:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,50}:[^:][ ]?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_\+]{1,50})$
                                                      ^ here
```

This is a feature of regular expressions, not Erlang specifically.

Comment: Argh! I even knew that! Thank you! (as well as @Michelle)